# 3D surface plot: How to invert the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

My Question: How we can change the axes for X, Y, Z. I have use ax.invert_yaxis()

Trying to create a 3D surface plot as below:

```
fig = plt.figure((10, 8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_title('3D Surface Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('IP')
ax.set_ylabel('VS')
ax.set_zlabel('TD')
x1 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
x2 = np.arange(0, 160, 1)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
F = (some logic)
surface = ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, F, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: This is default output]

But expect output is as below:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: `F = (some logic)` - please read [mre]. Does [how to rotate a 3D surface in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326983/how-to-rotate-a-3d-surface-in-matplotlib) answer your question? Or

Comment: [Rotating a 3d plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-rotate-axes3d-sgskip-py) - Matplotlib gallery example.

Comment: Did you try `ax.plot_surface(X2, X1, F...)`??

Comment: I tried ax.plot_surface(X2, X1, F) but no desired result)